# Include css file in asp file

Tags: css, asp.net, include

[image: fail to display:]

[image: it should be like this]

I would like to ask is my code of including css file in asp codes got error as the error display cannot get the css file.
So, what is the proper code to include css file?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="res/img/si.jpg">

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"  media="screen" href="~/library/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link href="library/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><!-- navi-->
<link href="library/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/> <!-- navi-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="library/startbootstrap-sb-admin-gh-pages/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"  type="text/css"/> <!-- navi-->

<!-- Bootstrap select css -->
<link href="library/bootstrap-select-1.10.0/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- navi-->

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="res/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- navi-->

<!-- C3.js CSS/JS  -->
<link href="library/c3-0.4.11/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- navi-->
<script src="library/d3/d3.min.js"></script><!-- navi-->
<script src="library/c3-0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script><!-- navi-->

<style>
    li {
border-left: 3px solid #ffffff;
        }
```

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="res/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="library/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap select Javascript -->
<script src="library/bootstrap-select-1.10.0//dist/js/bootstrap-
select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It should work if the files exist and the AppPool has rights to the files (although you would usually add a `/` in the source: `src="/res/js/...`). Are you getting a 404 error?

Comment: Are you in debug mode in VS?